# How to change Default Item Id used for Jomsocial links and menus in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, jomsocial, itemid

I'm using Jomsocial in my Joomla! website. I have created a module which is assigned to frontpage of the jomsocial menu item which is having `Item Id= 109`.

My problem is that for all menus and links on Jomsocial those does not contain Item ID in their link, `Item ID=109` is used automatically for those links. So that module is automatically shown on each such links or pages.

Please let me know how I can change the default Item id for such links inside Jomsocial.

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question, for me it is not clear if you want the articles to show in your jomsocial module or some there to not show? Or do you want to change which pages the module is on?

Answer (score 1):

JomSocial creates a menu as part of the installation. Most requirements are solved based on this menu.

Best practice: do not modify this menu and publish menu aliases to this menu instead

Answer (score 1):

If you install [Advanced Module Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/advanced-module-manager) (free extension), you'll get a lot more control over your modules and where they will be displayed/hidden. The extension has many filters and conditions, and I'm sure you'll be able to find a setting that hides the module, although I can't tell you exactly what setting will work in your specific case.

Hope that helps a little.